# Canvas doesn't clear clean after drawPath, works fine with drawCircle

Tags: android, opengl-es, path, android-canvas, shapes

I'm trying to draw various shapes. Here's my View's `onDraw`:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.invalidate();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    triangle.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    triangle.moveTo(shape.getX(), shape.getY());
    triangle.lineTo(shape.getX() - shape.getDiameter(), shape.getY() - shape.getDiameter());
    triangle.lineTo(shape.getX() + shape.getDiameter(), shape.getY() - shape.getDiameter());
    triangle.lineTo(shape.getX(), shape.getY());
    triangle.close();
    canvas.drawPath(triangle, paint);
}
```

`triangle` is a path, `shape` is a class I use to hold coordinates of shapes I draw on my view. The triangle's `x` and `y` coordinates change dynamically, so the shape is redrawn at a new position each turn.

But here is what it looks like:

[image]

It's important to note there is only a single triangle here, but the screen is being inefficiently cleared on each loop.

The exact same code using a `drawCircle` or `drawRect` instead of `drawPath` produces a clean and clear canvas with only the objects updated position.

Answer (score 1):

I've figure out my problem. When using a path it's necessary to reset it on each draw (see line 8):

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.invalidate();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    triangle.reset() // <------- add this
    triangle.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    triangle.moveTo(shape.getX(), shape.getY());
    triangle.lineTo(shape.getX() - shape.getDiameter(), shape.getY() - shape.getDiameter());
    triangle.lineTo(shape.getX() + shape.getDiameter(), shape.getY() - shape.getDiameter());
    triangle.lineTo(shape.getX(), shape.getY());
    triangle.close();
    canvas.drawPath(triangle, paint);
}
```